# "Focal tear of the [ligament name]" vs. "Tear of the [ligament name]"

Tags: terminology, mri, orthopedics, ligament

I am reading some MRI report and  see "Focal tear of the [ligament name]". what does the adjective add? In other words, what is the difference between "Focal tear of the [ligament name]"  and "Tear of the [ligament name]"?

https://www.google.com/search?q=focal+meaning&oq=focal+mean defines focal as:

> (of a disease or medical condition) occurring in one particular site in the body.

Does that mean that a focal tear of the [ligament name] is smaller in length than a "Tear of the [ligament name]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes, it definitely means it's a single point of injury. But if the report didn't specify any modifiers like "focal" or "diffuse" I wouldn't assume it says anything about length of the tear at all. I think it's only safe to say that using the word "focal" means it's a single, localized area. If it were more extensive, the report would have said "diffuse" or similar language.

According to [this site](https://www.mypathologyreport.ca/focal/), which I believe to be credible and reliable, pathologists use the word "focal" like this:

> **What does focal mean?**
>
> Focal is a word pathologists use to describe something seen in only a
> small part of the tissue sample examined. Focal changes can be seen
> when the tissue is examined by eye (this is called the gross
> examination) or under the microscope.
>
> The opposite of focal is diffuse. Pathologists use the word diffuse to
> describe something seen throughout the tissue sample examined. Like
> focal, diffuse changes can be seen when the tissue is examined by eye
> or under the microscope.